# SQL Join from multiple tables from a reference lookup into one view

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Im in the middle of a report creation. I came through these table structure which is really wierd and complicated. Im not able to create a view out of it.

I have two tables with structure

```
DBObjectType
-------------
TypeID,
Description
```

and

```
DBObAssign
----------
ID
ReferenceObType
ReferenceObID
TargetObType
TargetObID
```

The table is populated like :

```
DBObjectType table:

+--------+-------------------+
| TypeID  Description        |
+--------+-------------------+
| 1       Account            |
| 2       TFN                |
| 3       VDN                |
| 4       Skill              |
+--------+-------------------+

DBObAssign table
+----+-------------+---------+---------+--------+
| ID  RefObType    RefObID  TgtObType   TgtObID |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+--------+
| 1    1        12    2     23      |  => refer TFN Table
| 2    1        12    3     12      |  => refer VDN Table
| 3    1        23    4     1       |  => refer Skill Table
| 4    1        23    2     45      |  => refer TFN Table
| 5    1        23    4     31      |  =>refer Skill Table
+----+-------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

My report need to show all the TFN, VDN and skills for an account

Layout is something like:

```
+------+-------+------------+---------+     
|Account TFN    Skill         VDN |
+------+-------+------------+---------+
| 12    TFNof12       VDN@@@  |
| 23    TFNof23 Skill1of23            |
| 23        Skill2 of 23          |
+------+-------+------------+---------+
```

Right now Im only able to relate with only one table. That means Im joining  the account table only to get the TFN details.

```
select AccountName,TFN,Skill from tblAccount as acc 
left outer join tblDBAssign as DBA on DBA.RefObID = acc.id
left outer join tblDBobject as DBo on DBo.Description= 'TFN'
```

Is there any way to get the other records from the skill and vdn tables? Kindly provide some suggestions.

Table structure for

```
VDN:
---
VDNID
VDNDesc

TFN:
----
TFNID
TFNOwner
TFNDesc

Skill:
------
SkillID
SkillDesc
```

Comment: Post table structure of `TFN, VDN, Skill` tables

Comment: if you can create for 1 table same approach will be for other too. Just take same `LEFT JOINS` and create duplicates with different allias and DBo.Description

Comment: @Darka but how can i club the results and show it in one report? I'll try to do what u suggested now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should look something like this (note that this is not tested, also not clear about table names, which are different from what you gave in structure and sql example):

```
SELECT AccountName, t.TFNDesc, v.VDNDesc, s.SkillDesc 
FROM tblAccount AS acc 

LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBAssign as DBA1 
    ON DBA1.RefObID = acc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBobject as DBo1 
    ON DBo1.Description= 'TFN'
    AND DBA1.TgtObType =  DBo1.TypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TFN as t
    ON t.TFNID = DBA1.TgtObID

LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBAssign as DBA2 
    ON DBA2.RefObID = acc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBobject as DBo2 
    ON DBo2.Description= 'VDN'
    AND DBA2.TgtObType =  DBo2.TypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN VDN as v
    ON v.VDNID = DBA2.TgtObID

LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBAssign as DBA3 
    ON DBA3.RefObID = acc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDBobject as DBo2 
    ON DBo3.Description= 'Skill'
    AND DBA3.TgtObType =  DBo3.TypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill as s
    ON s.SkillID = DBA3.TgtObID
```